# jQuery post() and reading cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, cookies

I am using `jQuery.post()` to send data to the server, when the server sends data back to the client, the `post()` callback is invoked. I know that the data which the server sends has a `cookie`, and I would like to read it. In order to do so, I used `document.cookie` within the callback. Printing (alerting) the `document.cookie` does not hold the cookie, though using Firebug (or Chrome developer tools), the cookie appears.

Is there any way to access the cookie, which was returned by sending data to the server using `jQuery.post()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cookie is set with the [HttpOnly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie) flag you cannot read it from client scripts. Make sure that the server doesn't use this flag when setting the cookie if you ever hope to be able to read it from javascript.